# Hide datasource password in spring xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring, keystore, password-encryption

there is a way to hide/encrypt password in xml spring config file?
I read that is possible with a "custom" subclass of DataSource, but the solutions keep key in same config file as plain text...so is a bit useless.

There is a way to use KeyStore for this?
For example read the value from a keystore.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You will have to create a wrapper bean around the data source class. Here is an example of how I have done it before. Hope this helps!

```
<beans>
    <bean id="someDao" class="com.dao.SomeDAOImpl">
         <property name="datasource">
            <ref local="secureDataSource"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="secureDataSource" class="com.ds.SecureDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value><your driver></value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value><your url></value>
        </property>  
        <property name="username">
            <value><your user id></value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value><encrypted_pwd></value>
        </property> 
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Then inside the SecureDataSource class you will need to decrypt the password.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class SecureDataSource extends DriverManagerDataSource{

    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    /**
     * @param url the url to set
     */
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    /**
     * @param username the username to set
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    protected Connection getConnectionFromDriverManager() throws SQLException {
        String decryptedPassword = null;
        //decrypt the password here
        return getConnectionFromDriverManager(url,username,decryptedPassword);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be more flexible if you used the decorator pattern (e.g. your datasource contains another datasource and forwards everything except the password to it)

Comment: Touche S.P.! This was a quick one to show that it can be done. But the OP can redesign it however way he/she wants.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Would you have any pointer providing an example using the decorator pattern? Thanks.

Comment: @MarcdeVerdelhan an example is Spring's [DelegatingDataSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DelegatingDataSource.html). It delegates all methods to a wrapped DataSource, unless you override them.

Comment: @blow - the only thing this provides is false security. First of all, the decryption key has to be available to the app, and key + encrypted text = plain text. Second, you can take a heap dump shortly after connecting to the database and find the password there. Third, you can sniff the network traffic and get the password from there. You *can't* do this in a secure way.

Comment: @gustafc - It's mainly because a lot of organizations have mandates and regulations to not have passwords in clear text in any file. So they have to comply for that.

Comment: @CoolBeans, I'm really at a loss of words for *that* justification. I suppose that if you're content following the letter of the law rather than the intent, it's pretty OK. If you want to avoid security breaches, then it's not so good.

Comment: @gustafc - I did not ever mention it makes it more secured, just answering the OP's question about encrypting the password. Isn't that what StackOverflow is about?

Answer (score 12):

What is the purpose of hiding the password? I suggest you configure the datasource in the container (Tomcat, JBoss or whatever you use) and inject the datasource into your application using jndi:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="thedatasource"
                     jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/thedatasource"
                     lookup-on-startup="false"
                     expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

This way you have not to expose and password in your application but only in the servlet container.

Comment: i'm developing a desktop client-server application, and i want to protect application DB. I want to be unique that can touch my db.

Comment: Correct, for batch apps you will have to take a different approach.

Comment: To put it simpler: Just create a bean of class JndiObjectFactoryBean as your dataSource bean. `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"> <property name="jndiName" value="myDataResourceName" /> </bean>`

Answer (score 3):

Good options have been given, another obvious answer is to use the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer):

```
<context:property-placeholder
    system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" 
    location="classpath:database.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.whatever.datasource.you.Use">
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>
```

Now you can keep your password either as a property in a properties file (which you might create during deployment if you don't want to have it in the SCM) or as a System Property (which will hopefully also be beyond reach of other developers).

**Clarification:** *create during deployment* is somewhat vague. I guess you will have to write an installer that generates the properties file dynamically on the end user's machine, probably coupled with a sign up / log in mechanism.

---

**EDIT:** I still haven't figured out who you are hiding the information from. Two theories:

a) People who have access to your source code
b) Your customers

If it's a), then go my way. All other ways can easily be breached by the other developer just starting your application with a debugger (and suddenly he's inside the datasource object and sees the password).

If it's b), then you have no chance, basically. The customer has tons of possibilities to get at your password: debuggers, agents, bytecode manipulation, loadtime weaving etc. Even if he doesn't do any of that, he will just have to attach a port sniffer to get at the password in clear text. The only safe thing to do is have a username / password per customer (never store a global password at your customer's machine).

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer: i think to don't understand this. In this way, the password is store in database.properties, so anyone can read it, isn't true?

Comment: not if database.properties is e.g. dynamically created during deployment.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "deployment"? Deployment is when i release my software to user, you means this?

Comment: @blow: S.P. meant during building/packaging the project you can have a task that generates this property file.

Comment: If i generate this file during packaging anyone can open the file that is placed into my package... mmm i think i do not understand you.

Comment: @CoolBeans: Your approach is nice, i think to use it for my purpose.

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer: now everything is clear, my purpose is a+b, i think i will create dynamically propoerties file, but write into an encrypted password (AES maybe), and write a custom datasource that keep key hard coded and decrypt my password. I think it should be a good compromise.

Comment: @blow as I wrote, it's no good. a) Java can easily be decompiled, anybody who sees what you are doing can easily write some code to retrieve the password doing exactly what you do b) he doesn't even have to use Java, just a network sniffing tool. The password will be transmitted in clear text, unless your datasource is using a secure connection

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer: i know this, but i think this is enough. If someone want retrive the password(and know how to do) has to spend some time, and this is good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question recently. I wanted to store a hashed version of the password in a .properties file.
I did the trick thanks to the previous options: I extended the `DelegatingDataSource` and overrided the `getConnection([...])` methods.

```
public class UnhashingDataSource extends DelegatingDataSource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UnhashingDataSource.class);
    private static final int HEX_RADIX = 16;
    private static final String DB_PASS = "a_sample_password";

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = (DriverManagerDataSource) getTargetDataSource();
        return getConnection(dataSource.getUsername(), dataSource.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        try {
            DataSource datasource = getTargetDataSource();
            if (datasource == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("targetDataSource is null");
            }
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.reset();
            md.update(DB_PASS.getBytes());
            if (password.equals(getHexString(md.digest()))) {
                return datasource.getConnection(username, DB_PASS);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to connect to DB");
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unknown algorithm");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String getHexString(final byte[] messageDigest) {
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
        return bigInt.toString(HEX_RADIX);
    }
}
```

Then, here is how I used it in my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
# Using the unhashing datasource
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="unhashingDataSource" />
    # ...
</bean>
<bean id="hashedDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${datasource.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${datasource.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${datasource.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${datasource.hash}" />
</bean>
<bean id="unhashingDataSource"
    class="my.package.UnhashingDataSource">
    <property name="targetDataSource" ref="hashedDataSource" />
</bean>
```

Where `datasource.hash` is a property (from a .properties file) stored like:

```
datasource.hash = 2e54b0667ef542e3398c55a08a4e04e69b9769e8
```

The plain password is still in bytecode but not directly in a .properties file anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your post and queries.

Hope for visitors its clear the technical way to encrypt password by reading this page. One important thing I would like to add here, if you are dealing with production then definitely will suggest you to use any "Secure Hash Algorithm" like SHA-256 with salt. You can consider secure hash algorithm using salt as industry standard.