# Hide password in Oauth2 token request URL

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We are building a RESTful web application using java, jersey and spring-security.
An OAuth2 provider service for protecting access to REST resources is set up.

To request a valid refresh token token, following query parameters have to be provided:

- username
- password
- client_id
- grant_type

The username/password are provided by the login dialog in the front end:

[image: login dialog]

But when I inspect the network traffic of the application, I see following the URL passing by, where the password is shown in clear text:

[image: password in clear]

Is there an easy way to hide the password in the request URL when sending it to the OAuth2 provider?
Is it possible to achieve this by the spring-security configuration?

This is my spring-security configuration of the authorization server:

```
<!-- Token management -->
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler" token-endpoint-url="/oauth/token">
    <oauth:authorization-code/>
    <oauth:implicit/>
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:password/>
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196545/hide-datasource-password-in-spring-xml-file

Comment: @javadev This is not what I'm looking for. I want to hide the password in the oauth2 url, not hiding passwords in a spring configuration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to use HTTPS end-point. The Secured version perform handshake before sending any data. Once a secured connection is made all the query parameters are encrypted. Hope that make sense.

The documentation at [Security Namespace Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html). The section *3.3.2 Adding HTTP/HTTPS Channel Security* will help you in implementing this.

This is also helpful [Here](http://mattfleming.com/node/289)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is the goal to make our endpoint an HTTPS endpoint. Nice to know that a secured connection will encrypt all the query parameters. This would solve my issue. What I was also thinking: is there a way to pass the username/password in the header, instead of as a query parameter?

Comment: @MathiasGhys, You can use Basic authentication(BA), once you create a Secure connection with the server. In BA the data is Base 64 encoded but everything will again be encrypted. So this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@KhushalDave Thanks for your replies.

I created a self-signed keystore and enabled SSL authentication on port 8443 on my local Tomcat application server using following tutorial: [Tomcat SSL configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Next I protected every call to the /oauth/token url indicating in my spring-security.xml that the https channel is required using **requires-channel="https"** attribute:

```
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" requires-channel="https" />
```

Now when I make the call to my /oauth/token url on my local server, the call is secured using SSL.

When I inspect the network traffic in my browser (google chrome), I still see the password in clear.

[image: Password in clear]

I guess this isn't that bad, since it's just logging the data that is typed in the address bar of the browser... As long as the query parameters are protected on network level it's ok I guess.

Maybe I should use a program like [Eavesdrop](http://www.baurhome.net/software/eavesdrop/index.html) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to verify the password is protected on network level.

Comment: I know it's slightly off what your question states. Correct me If I am wrong but the OAuth 2 spec allows for such credentials to be sent as form parameters. At least that's what the implementation used within the `FOSOAuthServerBundle` (PHP) outlines. This would hide this information from the URL and potential log files.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this for a while You are absolutely correct. The URL will get encrypted and parameters won't be visible.